# Merge or combine vertex in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a list of repeated nodes (vertex) in an igraph file that I would like to unify while keeping the connections.
In my example I have an author listed as:

```
R, 2000-1
R, 2000-2
J, 1999-1
J, 1999-2
J, 1999-3
```

And it would have to be a single author like

```
R, 2000
J, 1999
```

I've been looking for a solution all day but I haven't been able to do it in a simple way. I have also tried to go from igraph to csv and back to igraph again, but this option gives me problems (I lose some connections between edges).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `igraph`. You can try the following base R code

```
unique(
  transform(
    df,
    V2 = gsub("-\\d+", "", V2)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  V1   V2
1  R 2000
3  J 1999
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c("R", "R", "J", "J", "J"), V2 = c("2000-1",
"2000-2", "1999-1", "1999-2", "1999-3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))
```